# Troubleshoot SNMP - NPEG2 - Purpose of snmp mib community-map <community> engineid command

Tags: router, cisco-ios, snmp, cisco-7200

we have several cisco 7225 vxr deployed on our network and we have an issue on SNMP access.

On last new deployment, we can't reach the last router implemented through SNMP. Comparing two router with similar config (change only IP address) rest it's the same, we can't reach on SNMP the last deployed Router.

From our monitoring server, we can ping both machine 10.30.0.12 and 10.30.0.40. 
And we reach over SNMP 10.30.0.12

Output server :

```
MON # ping 10.30.0.12
PING 10.30.0.12 (10.30.0.12): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.30.0.12: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=1.288 ms
64 bytes from 10.30.0.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=1.270 ms
^C
--- 10.30.0.12 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.270/1.279/1.288/0.009 ms
MON # snmpwalk -v 2c -c comm3 10.30.0.12
^C
MON # snmpwalk -v 2c -c comm3 10.30.0.12
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Cisco IOS Software, 7200 Software (UBR7200P-JK9SU2-M), Version 12.2(33)SCG6, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2013 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Thu 31-Oct-13 13:45 by prod_rel_team
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: CISCO-DOCS-EXT-MIB::cisco.1.827

MON # ping 10.30.0.40
PING 10.30.0.40 (10.30.0.40): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.30.0.40: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=1.034 ms
64 bytes from 10.30.0.40: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=0.945 ms
^C
--- 10.30.0.40 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.945/0.990/1.034/0.044 ms
MON # snmpwalk -v 2c -c comm3 10.30.0.40
Timeout: No Response from 10.30.0.40
```

SNMP configuration (output from `show run all`) same on both router :

```
snmp-server group ADM v3 auth match exact read v1default write CFGCOPY access 8
snmp-server view *ilmi system included
snmp-server view *ilmi atmForumUni included
snmp-server view CFGCOPY ccCopyTable.* included
snmp-server view v1default iso included
snmp-server view v1default internet included
snmp-server view v1default snmpMPDMIB excluded
snmp-server view v1default snmpTargetMIB excluded
snmp-server view v1default snmpNotificationMIB excluded
snmp-server view v1default snmpUsmMIB excluded
snmp-server view v1default snmpVacmMIB excluded
snmp-server view v1default snmpCommunityMIB excluded
snmp-server view v1default ciscoIpTapMIB excluded
snmp-server view v1default cisco802TapMIB excluded
snmp-server view v1default ciscoTap2MIB excluded
snmp-server view v1default ciscoUserConnectionTapMIB excluded
snmp-server view *tv.00000000.00000010.00000080.000000007F iso.2.840.10036 included
snmp-server view *tv.00000000.00000010.00000080.000000007F internet included
snmp-server view *tv.FFFFFFFF.FFFFFFFF.FFFFFFFF.FFFFFFFF7F iso.2.840.10036 included
snmp-server view *tv.FFFFFFFF.FFFFFFFF.FFFFFFFF.FFFFFFFF7F internet included
snmp-server community comm1default RO 1
snmp-server community comm2default RO 2
snmp-server community comm3default RW 3
snmp-server community comm4default RO 51
snmp-server priority normal
no snmp-server trap link ietf
no snmp-server trap link switchover
snmp-server trap authentication vrf
snmp-server trap authentication acl-failure
snmp-server trap retry 3
snmp-server trap-source Loopback1
snmp-server packetsize 1500
snmp-server trap timeout 30
snmp-server queue-length 10
snmp-server location Hub
snmp-server contact 0461523
snmp-server chassis-id SN
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkdown linkup coldstart warmstart
snmp-server enable traps tty
snmp-server enable traps config
snmp-server enable traps entity
snmp-server enable traps envmon fan shutdown supply temperature
snmp-server enable traps cable
snmp-server enable traps rtr
snmp-server host 10.10.254.10 traps version 1 comm1 udp-port 162 
snmp-server host 10.10.10.253 traps version 1 comm1 udp-port 162 
snmp-server host 10.11.161.11 traps version 1 comm1 udp-port 162 
snmp-server host 10.11.168.240 traps version 1 comm1 udp-port 162 
snmp-server host 10.11.126.96 traps version 2c comm1 udp-port 162 
snmp-server host 10.11.167.5 traps version 1 public udp-port 162  comm1 docsis-cmts
snmp-server manager session-timeout 600
snmp-server manager
snmp-server inform retries 3 timeout 15 pending 25
snmp ifmib ifindex persist
snmp mib notification-log globalsize 500
snmp mib notification-log globalageout 15
snmp mib community-map  comm1 engineid 800000090300A44C11809A1B
snmp mib community-map  comm2 engineid 800000090300A44C11809A1B
snmp mib community-map  comm3 engineid 800000090300A44C11809A1B
snmp mib community-map  comm4 engineid 800000090300A44C11809A1B
snmp mib community-map  comm5 engineid 80000009030024E9B301AC1B
snmp mib community-map  comm6 engineid 800000090300A44C11809A1B
```

Edit1:
Solution :
- Removing the `snmp mib community-map` command solve the issue and I get access to router through SNMP.

What is the purpose of such command ? Why on this router isn't working and on the others it is.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **snmp mib community-map**
>
> To associate a Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) community
> with an SNMP context, engine ID, or security name, use the snmp mib
> community-map command in global configuration mode. To change an SNMP
> community mapping to its default mapping, use the no form of this
> command.

[Cisco IOS Network Management Command Reference](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/netmgmt/command/reference/nm_book/nm_16.html#wp1024742)

This fails when copying configs between routers because each will have a unique engineid. On the clone router, you've associated all your communities with a non-existent engineid.  I'm not sure there's a way to force IOS to use the same (user supplied) engineid.

[**UPDATE**]
So you can... `snmp-server engineID local 800000090300A44C11809A1B` (I don't recommend doing that, 'tho)